# How to pass data to dynamically nested custom elements in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte

The CMS returns HTML with custom elements with respective props.

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<svelte-accordion props='{"toggleAll":true}'>
  <svelte-accordion-item props='{"title":"Accordion item 1"}'>
    <p>Content of the first accordion item</p>
  </svelte-accordion-item>
  <svelte-accordion-item props='{"title":"Accordion item 2"}'>
    <p>Content of the second accordion item</p>
  </svelte-accordion-item>
  <svelte-accordion-item props='{"title":"Accordion item 3"}'>
    <p>Content of the third accordion item</p>
  </svelte-accordion-item>
</svelte-accordion>
```

The idea is to use Svelte components for the custom elements like this:

```html
// Accordion.svelte

<svelte:options tag="svelte-accordion" />

<script>
  export let props;
</script>

<slot parentProps={props} />
```

```html
// AccordionItem.svelte

<svelte:options tag="svelte-accordion-item" />

<script>
  export let props;
  export let parentProps;
  const { title } = JSON.parse(props);

  // parentProps is undefined
  console.info('__parentProps__', parentProps);
</script>

<h2>{title}</h2>
<slot />
```

In the above example `AccordionItem.svelte` is unable to receive the props passed by `Accordion.svelte`. The reason may be that the props are actually passed to the `<slot>` within `Accordion.svelte` and not directly to `<svelte-accordion-item>`.

How can we solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See this - https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props

Comment: Thanks, @Pythony! Slot props are not working in my case, maybe because `svelte-accordion-item` is dynamically inserted by the CMS in the page markup.

Comment: *"...are actually passed to the <slot> within Accordion.svelte and not directly to <svelte-accordion-item>."* Why don't you pass the `parentprops` directly in `index.html` like `<svelte-accordion-item props='{"title":"Accordion item 1"}' parentprops='{"toggleAll":true}'>` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `<slot parentProps={props}>` the *parentProps* are not automatically send to the content of the prop, but are instead available in the form of `let:parentProps` on the `Accordion` component. Note that this makes perfect sense if you consider that you do not have to use a component to fill a *slot*:

```html
<Accordion>
  <span>Some content here</span>
</Accordion>
```

In the above example there is not **Component** to send those props to!

To solve your problem you could consider using the `ContextAPI` this allows us to make variables available to all the descendants of a component.

```html
<!-- Accordion.svelte -->

<svelte:options tag="svelte-accordion" />

<script>
  import { setContext } from 'svelte';
  export let props;
  setContext('parentProps', props)
</script>

<slot />
```

```
<!-- AccordionItem.svelte -->
<svelte:options tag="svelte-accordion-item" />

<script>
  import { getContext } from 'svelte';
  export let props;

  const parentProps = getContext('parentProps');
  const { title } = JSON.parse(props);

  // parentProps is undefined
  console.info('__parentProps__', parentProps);
</script>

<h2>{title}</h2>
<slot />
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stephane, Context API is not working in my case, maybe because `svelte-accordion-item` is dynamic, and not called by `Accordion.svelte`.

Comment: I would have to check, it is possible the ContextAPI does not work with custom elements, them being dynamic should not be a problem because that is exactly what this is meant for.

Comment: `getContext('parentProps')` is working when `<AccordionItem />` is rendered manually within `AccordionItem.svelte`, but not when it renders as a custom element through `<slot />`

Comment: The `<slot>` part has nothing to do with it, that works fine.  It seems custom elements cannot use `getContext`, there is a long standing open issue about that https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3422

Comment: Seems your only option for now is to also pass the parentProps manually to all items.